# Handle exception's causes differently

Tags: java, exception

In one of my software, I'm using a library that is basically a protocol implementation. The library is structured according to the five first OSI layers (physical to session).

I have to use the session layer with this interface

```
public interface ReadSession {
    Iterable<byte[]> read(boolean fromStart, byte dataset, int nbData) throws SessionException;
}
```

Now my problem is that, according to the inner (or inner's inner, etc.) cause I need my software to behave differently.

Examples (> represents the inner cause relation):

If `SessionException > IOException > ...` then I should abort all the communications

If `SessionException > TransportException > NetworkException > ...` then I should log the exception and proceed with the next communication

If `SessionException > TransportException > GatewayException > ...` then I should warn the user that there's a problem with its gateway

But all what I have at the moment is a single catch

```
catch(SessionException e) {
    //How to handle this problematic properly ?
}
```

I feel myself not comfortable with a fixed number of call to `getCause()` because:

- of the lot of null checks involved
- I rely on the implementation details of the library ([leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction)) and if these change in the future I'm screwed

Has anyone already faced such a situation and want to share his knowledge about how to handle it as cleanly as possible ?

Comment: How will you know the cause without calling `getCause()` ?

Comment: @Berger I know I can't without calling `getCause()` ever. But I'd like to avoid to hardcode the chain of `getCause()`. Maybe with some loop ?

Comment: Don't rely on the implementation details of the library, is there no other way to do it in a clean way?

Comment: @michael_bitard Yep, that's exactly that. I don't want to rely on implementation's details and I'm here to know if there's a clean way to handle this situation... :-)

Comment: @Spotted ;) What i really meant was: is there no other higher level way to do what you want to do?

Comment: @Spotted But the information you want is from the implementation detail? Do you want Fuzzy matching?

Comment: @michael_bitard What do you mean by "higher level way" ?

Comment: @waltersu That's right, I know I'll have to break the abstraction at some point but I want to find the least bad solution. Involving fuzzy matching in the loop seems too much. I'm rather considering using `getCause()` but with some loop instead of hardcoding the chain.

Comment: @Spotted I mean a complete different way of achieving what you are trying to do. I'm sorry I can be more precise. I think it's called a paradigm shift: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm_shift Try to look at the bigger picture to see if what you are trying to achieve is the only way to do it

Comment: @michael_bitard I already made this but I think I'm stuck with this approach because on one side are the specs that require to handle these cases differently for the final user and on the other side is this library that I can't freely update to achieve a better handling of this situation.

Comment: So unfortunately it seems that @michael-markidis's solution is your best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something like this:

```
catch(SessionException e) {
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    while(cause != null) {
        if(cause instanceof NetworkException.class) {
            //Trigger some logic
        }
        else if(...)
        cause = cause.getCause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach here is to create a List of the causes in your single catch block.

**For example**:

```
catch (SessionException t)
{
    List<String> causeList = new ArrayList<>();
    do
    {
        causeList.add(t.getClass().getName());
        t = t.getCause();

    } while(t != null);
}
```

Then what you can do is compare the `causeList` with a set of predefined cause lists that you hardcode. When you find that the `causeList` equals one of your predefined lists, then you take the appropriate path of code.

A predefined List can look something like:

```
final List<String> ABORT_LIST = new ArrayList<String>
   (Arrays.asList("com.package.SessionException", "java.io.IOException"));
```

Then, after you build the `causeList` in the catch block, you can do something like this:

```
if (causeList.equals(ABORT_LIST))
{
    System.out.println("Aborting...");
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't guess the **whole** causes list. The point is that below the cause that matters to me (`IOException`, `NetworkException`, `GatewayException`) lies a chain of other causes that I can't predict.

Comment: Then instead of doing a straight equals comparison on the two lists, implement a startsWith method that looks at the two lists and returns true if the causeList startsWith your predefined list; false otherwise.

Comment: Indeed, but even so I decided to stick with another solution that I find less verbose (see my answer).